# Pattern Match on Tuple Values within 'for-comprension'?

Tags: scala

Given:

```
scala> val x: Either[Boolean, (Int, Int)] = Right( (5, 10) )
x: Either[Boolean,(Int, Int)] = Right((5,10))
```

I'd like to pattern match on the first and second tuple values in `x.right`, but this didn't work:

```
scala> for { 
     |   (a, b) <- x.right
         | } yield a

<console>:14: error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : (T1, T2)
 required: scala.util.Either[Nothing,(Int, Int)]
         (a, b) <- x.right
         ^
```

I can do something like:

```
scala> for { a <- x.right } yield a match { case (x, y) => x }
res5: scala.util.Either[Boolean,Int] = Right(5)
```

But, is there any way for me to change my first, non-compiling code to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known bug. See [SI-7222](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7222).

For now, if you're going to rely on `RightProjection`, you'll have to match the entire tuple, and use the `_1` and `_2` accessors.

You could also use a right-biased `Either` such as `scalaz.\/`, though that would require `Monoid[Boolean]` in this example.